# Unison doesn't copy SYSTEM perm (cygwin/windows)

Tags: permissions, cygwin, unison

After using crashplan for a while, I noticed that several files aren't being backed up. The files are synced via unison (through cygwin) with another PC and while the *nix permissions are copied correctly, the mirrored file does not have SYSTEM as a user (in windows). Therefore, crashplan can't back it up. Both client and server are running cygwin.

What's the best solution? Can I copy this permission as well with unison? Can I do it with a script (in cygwin or cmd)?

Thanks
Sander

EDIT: To fix it short term I ran an icacls command, but I'm still looking for a way to copy the ACLs via unison whilst syncing.

Answer (score 0):

[Relevant section from the Unison Manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#perms):

> **Permissions**
>
> Synchronizing the permission bits of files is slightly tricky when two different filesytems are involved (e.g., when synchronizing a Windows client and a Unix server). In detail, here's how it works:
>
> - When the permission bits of an existing file or directory are changed, the values of those bits that make sense on both operating systems will be propagated to the other replica. The other bits will not be changed.
> - When a newly created file is propagated to a remote replica, the permission bits that make sense in both operating systems are also propagated. The values of the other bits are set to default values (they are taken from the current umask, if the receiving host is a Unix system).
> - For security reasons, the Unix setuid and setgid bits are not propagated.
> - The Unix owner and group ids are not propagated. (What would this mean, in general?) All files are created with the owner and group of the server process.